# How to convert Rails 3.2 datamapper validation to activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, datamapper

I have a rails 3.2 app using datamapper validations that I need to convert to active record. The existing code looks like this:

```
validates_with_method :quota
```

I tried the same thing with active record and my rspec test crashes with:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `validates_with_method' for #<Class:0x00000004ebcc70> (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried

```
validates_with :quota
```

and that crashes with:

```
`block in validates_with': undefined method `new' for :quota:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

How can I define a simple validation callback with active record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `validate` to [validate with custom method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).